# how to generate Data Base DB script in MySQL (MySQL Query Browser / Toad for MySQL)

Tags: sql, mysql

I need to **Generate** an export **script** of entire MYSQL Database ,

currently i am using

```
      MySQL Query Browser 
  and 
      Toad for MySQL
```

so How can I Generate the script of entire DB.

As i need to only copy structure of Table , procedures to other DataBase

Comment: alternate tool - dbForge Studio for MySQL (backup or generate schema script features); objects you can select in a GUI tree.

Comment: one more tool is a mysqldump command line program, you could use with a '--no-data' and '--routines' options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LogOn to MySQL Administrator.

Click on BackUp --> on the Left Panel

in BackUp Project Tab 
--> Enter the backUp name in 
Select Schemata the name of Db you need to generate script / Bk

click on ">"

--> Click on New "Execute Backup Now"

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) feature of the mysql itself if you are on the machine that the MySQL is installed on.

if you are trying to create a dump from a remote machine you should use the [Toad for MySQL Export Wizard](http://www.toadworld.com/KNOWLEDGE/ToadKnowledge/TipsandTricks/tabid/74/TID/290/cid/38/Default.aspx)

Comment: mysqldump can connect to remote machine too.

Comment: @Devart : you are absolutely correct, however not all machines have MySQL installed on them, so seeing as he already stated he has Toad installed i thought it would be more helpful to point him in a direction he will surely be able to use